# How to send notification from BLE device to hardware using ANCS in ios

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, core-bluetooth

I am new in iOS. I need to send notification from BLE device to hardware using ANCS and core bluetooth framework in ios. I came to know that ANCS itself will do task but from my side what kind of code I have to do for sending notification. Please help me to resolve it step by step. Thanks in advance.